# How does one solve this

Tags: probability

If x~Po(6)then find 
$$P(x=6|5≤ x ≤ 8 )$$
I understand that this is conditional probability but I do not understand how would you solve it?

Comment: Must $x$ take on integer values only? Is your distribution function uniform?

Comment: its a poisson distribution

Comment: OK, I was wondering what the $x\sim Po(6)$ meant.

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align}P(X=6|5 \leq X \leq 8)&=\frac{P(X=6)}{P(5 \leq X \leq 8)}\\&=\frac{P(X=6)}{\sum_{i=5}^8P(X=i)}
\\&=\frac{\exp(-\lambda)\frac{\lambda^6}{6!}}{\sum_{i=5}^8\exp(-\lambda)\frac{\lambda^i}{i!}}
\\&=\frac{\frac{\lambda^6}{6!}}{\sum_{i=5}^8\frac{\lambda^i}{i!}}\end{align}

where $\lambda = 6$.